# Confusing output when using CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: nsstring, double, cllocationcoordinate2d

Consider this code:

```
NSString * coordinateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@,%@}", [inPoint objectAtIndex:0],[inPoint objectAtIndex:1]];
CLLocationCoordinate2D  * myPoint= (__bridge CLLocationCoordinate2D *)(coordinateString);
```

My question is:
In this example the value of

```
[inPoint objectAtIndex:0] and [inPoint objectAtIndex:0]
```

are respectively 16.4006 and 38.254

If I log the value of myPoint, I get "myPoint=(16.400583,38.254028}".
Just as a I expected. However, in the Debug Panel, myPoint is represented with a latitude of 7304.....-304 and a longitude of endless zeroes.

Is this an internal representation, or is something lost in translation from double to NSString to CLLocationCoordinate2D?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is relevant to somebody: I eventually fixed this with the following code:

```
float lat = [[inPoint objectAtIndex:0]floatValue];
float lng = [[inPoint objectAtIndex:1]floatValue];

CLLocationCoordinate2D myPoint = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);
```

The input was a double, and apparently needed to be converted to float.